# python Opencv error -215 scn ==3 || scn == 4

Tags: python, opencv

I am using python 2.7 on windows 8.1 while working with python-tesseract-0.9-0.4.win32-py2.7 my previous code's weren't working properly like face detection.
The code below is to detect face in a pic. It works fine when I uninstall  python-tesseract-0.9-0.4.win32-py2.7. But I need it for OCR. 
what should  I do.? 
the error is : `open cv error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor`

```
import cv2
import sys

imagepath = ('C:\Users\Default\Downloads\group1.jpg')
cascpath  ('C:\opencv\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
caspatheye=('C:\opencv\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_eye.xml')

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascpath)
eye_cascade  = cv2.CascadeClassifier(caspatheye)

img = cv2.imread(imagepath)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
gray,
scaleFactor=1.3,
minNeighbors=5,
minSize=(15,15),
flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),((x+w),(y+h)),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
         cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.namedWindow("faces found", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("faces found",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Use double slashes "\\" in paths

Comment: Hi, Miki, double slashes works in general, but when I install[ python-tesseract-0.9-0.4.win32-py2.7] and then I run the same code I get an error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aquib Javed Khan\Desktop\fabproject\checkingface.py", line 26, in <module>
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: That's another error, and another question :D